# get correct data in callback in python dash

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I try to take the values of the `table2` in the function `def actualizar_makespan`, this table has a `id='tablaresultados'`, but when I do change in the values of tabla-editable and I try to take the data is not update in the variable `problem` but the data in the webpage is uptade, i do a print(problem) for watch the data but always the values is zeros

```
import dash
from dash import html, dash_table
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#creo el dataframe
data = {'Operario': ['Eficiencia'],
        'A': ['65%'],
        'B': ['80%'],
        'C': ['75%'],
        'D': ['100%'],
        'E': ['75%'],
        'F': ['80%'],
        'G': ['60%'],
        'H': ['60%'],
        'I': ['90%'],
        'J': ['95%'],
        'K': ['75%'],
        'L': ['90%']}

tabla2  = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2= {'Referencia': ['T05', 'T10', 'T50', 'T75', 'T150', 'T200', 'T250', 'T500'],
        'Tiempo_estándar': [20, 45, 25, 50, 90, 110, 120, 150],
        'Requerimiento': [8, 10, 12, 9, 7, 15, 10, 7],
        'A': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
        'B': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'C': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'D': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'E': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'F': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'G': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'H': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'I': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'J': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'K': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'L': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        'Total': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

tabla3  = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = {
    'Operario': ['Terminación'],
    'A': [0],
    'B': [0],
    'C': [0],
    'D': [0],
    'E': [0],
    'F': [0],
    'G': [0],
    'H': [0],
    'I': [0],
    'J': [0],
    'K': [0],
    'L': [0]
}

tabla4  = pd.DataFrame(data3)

# Crea la tabla
table = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=tabla3.to_dict('records'),
    id='tabla-editable',
    columns=[
        {'name': 'Referencia', 'id': 'Referencia', 'editable': False},
        {'name': 'Tiempo_estándar', 'id': 'Tiempo_estándar', 'editable': False},
        {'name': 'Requerimiento', 'id': 'Requerimiento', 'editable': False},
        {'name': 'A', 'id': 'A', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'B', 'id': 'B', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'C', 'id': 'C', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'D', 'id': 'D', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'E', 'id': 'E', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'F', 'id': 'F', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'G', 'id': 'G', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'H', 'id': 'H', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'I', 'id': 'I', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'J', 'id': 'J', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'K', 'id': 'K', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'L', 'id': 'L', 'editable': True, 'type': 'numeric'},
        {'name': 'Total', 'id': 'Total', 'editable': False}
    ],
    editable=True,
)

table2 = dash_table.DataTable(
            id='tablaresultados',
            data=tabla4.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in tabla4.columns],
            style_table={
                'maxWidth': '800px',
                'margin': '1rem auto',
                'overflowX': 'auto'
            }
)

# Definir el callback para actualizar la tabla1
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('tabla-editable', 'data'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('tabla-editable', 'data_timestamp')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('tabla-editable', 'data')]
)

def actualizar_tabla1(timestamp, data):
    tabla3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
    tabla3['Total'] = tabla3[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum(axis=1)
    return tabla3.to_dict('records')

#Definir el callback para actualizar la tabla2
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('tablaresultados', 'data'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('tabla-editable', 'data_timestamp')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('tabla-editable', 'data')]
)

def actualizar_tabla4(timestamp, data):
    tabla3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
    columnas = tabla2.columns.tolist()
    columnas.pop(0)
    listadeTE = tabla3['Tiempo_estándar'].values.tolist()
    listasolucion=[]

    for operario in columnas:
        listadeA = tabla3[operario].values.tolist()
        suma_producto = sum([x * y for x, y in zip(listadeA, listadeTE)])
        porcentaje_str = tabla2[operario][0]
        porcentaje_num = float(porcentaje_str[:-1])/100.0
        listasolucion.append(round(suma_producto/porcentaje_num,2))

    index=0
    for operario in columnas:
        tabla4.loc[0, operario] = listasolucion[index]
        index+=1
    return tabla4.to_dict('records')

#Definir el callback para actualizar EL MAKESPAN

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('valor-makespan', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('tablaresultados', 'data_timestamp')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('tablaresultados', 'data')]
)
def actualizar_makespan(timestamp, data):
    #AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA!!!
    problem = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(problem)
    value = 10  
    return value

# Crea el diseño de la aplicación
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Ejemplo de tabla editable en Dash'),
    table,
    table2, 
     html.Div([
        html.H2('Makespan: ',
                style={
                    'textAlign': 'center',
                    'color': 'rgb(243, 245, 244)',
                    'fontSize': '2rem'
                }),

        html.B(id='valor-makespan',
               style={
                   'textAlign': 'center',
                   'color': 'rgb(9, 205, 205)',
                   'fontSize': '3rem',
                   'display': 'block',
                   'margin': '1rem'
               }),
    ])
])

# Ejecuta la aplicación
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

i need save in variable "problem" the data when the data change in table2 (id='tablaresultados') and take the max of values and return it